# react It remains checked even after deletion

Tags: reactjs

I select the item I want to delete and then delete it. Then, the remaining items appear as checked.

if there are item1, item2, item3, item4 and check items 1,2 and delete them. 
Then, only items 3 and 4 are left, but rendered as checked. How can I initialize it?

```
this.state = {
    options: [],
    subject: []
    ....
}

_delete() {
    const selected = this.state.options
    const newList = this.state.subject

    if(selected.length !== 0){
        if(selected.length > 1){
            let i
            selected.sort(function(a, b) {
                return b - a;
                // 11, 10, 4, 3, 2, 1
            });
            for(i=0; i<selected.length; i++){
                newList.splice(selected[i],1)
            }
        }

        else{
            newList.splice(selected[0],1)
        }     
    }

    this.setState({options: [], subject: newList})


render(){
    return(
        {this.state.subject.map((item, index) => {
                        return <TableRow style={{'alignItems':'center'}}>
                            <TableCell style={{"textAlign":"center"}}><Checkbox onChange={function(e){
                                const selected = this.state.options
                                let cancel

                                if(e.target.checked){
                                    selected.push(index)
                                }

                                else{
                                    cancel = selected.indexOf(index)
                                    selected.splice(cancel,1)
                                }
                                this.setState({
                                    options: selected
                                })
                            }.bind(this)}></Checkbox></TableCell>
                            <TableCell style={{"textAlign":"center"}}>{item.fields.course_year}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell style={{"textAlign":"center"}}>{item.fields.course_semester}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell style={{"textAlign":"center"}}>{item.fields.course_colgnm}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell style={{"textAlign":"center"}}>{item.fields.course_sustnm}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell style={{"textAlign":"center"}}>{item.fields.course_pobjnm}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell style={{"textAlign":"center"}}>{item.fields.course_sbjtclss}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell style={{"textAlign":"center"}}>{item.fields.course_clssnm}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell style={{"textAlign":"center"}}>{item.fields.course_pnt}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell style={{"textAlign":"center"}}>{item.fields.course_remk}</TableCell>                                
                        </TableRow>}
                    )}

        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" size='large' onClick={this._delete.bind(this)}>delete</Button?
    );
}
```

Is the point of change of state a problem?

Comment: I'll guess that if you open your console, you'll see a warning from react about missing `key` prop.

Comment: You have made very big mistakes , in _delete state modification must be immutable,  `selected.sort` big no no, using splice.You might think const a = b; creates copy of b but this is wrong! It only creates shallow copy , read react state management and immutablilty first!